# Why this CancellationDisposable never get canceled on Observable.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, system.reactive

Im using RxFramework within an WinForms app. Im trying to run an Observable async and using the CancellationDisposable to cancel the operation when user clicks a button. but it is not working!

Suppose I have a form with 2 buttons and a ProgressBar. Button1_click subscribe to the observer on a new Thread. Button2_click is then pressed right after to cancel the operation.
Why **cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested** is never true?

```
private IDisposable obs = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var countObserver = Observable.Create<int>(observer => {
        var cancel = new CancellationDisposable();

        if (!cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            //Step 1 of a long running process using lot of resources...
            observer.OnNext(1);
        }
        if (!cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            //Step 2 of a long running process using lot of resources...
            observer.OnNext(1);
        }
        if (!cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            //Step 3 of a long running process using lot of resources...
            observer.OnNext(1);
        }
        observer.OnCompleted();

        return cancel;
    });

    obs = countObserver
        .ObserveOn(new ControlScheduler(this))
        .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
        .Subscribe(i => {
            //Update a progress bar here...
        });

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (obs != null)
        obs.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens so because the lambda you pass to `Observable.Create` does not return the `CancellationDisposable` **until** it goes through all the steps. So, the order of actions is the following:

1. You call `Subscribe`
2. UI thread blocks
3. On a `ThreadPool` thread, the execution enters the lambda
4. `CancellationDisposable` is created
5. You check for cancellation several times and execute the whole process. During this, your progress bar is updated.
6. `cancel` is returned from lambda
7. UI thread is released and `obs` gets its value
8. You click `Button2` and call `obs.Dispose`
9. `cancel` gets `cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested=true`. But nothing happens since everything has already happened.

Here's the fixed code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var countObserver = Observable.Create<int>(observer => {
    var cancel = new CancellationDisposable();

    // Here's the magic: schedule the job in background and return quickly
    var scheduledItem = Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(() =>
    {
      if (!cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        //Step 1 of a long running process using lot of resources...
        observer.OnNext(1);
      }
      if (!cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        //Step 2 of a long running process using lot of resources...
        observer.OnNext(1);
      }
      if (!cancel.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        //Step 3 of a long running process using lot of resources...
        observer.OnNext(1);
      }
      observer.OnCompleted();
    });

    return new CompositeDisposable(cancel, scheduledItem);
});

obs = countObserver
    .ObserveOn(new ControlScheduler(this))
    .Subscribe(i => {
        //Update a progress bar here...
    });

}
```

Comment: Should OnCompleted be called if the observable is disposed ahead of time? What does Rx guidelines say here?

Comment: @BentRasmussen I am not sure, but I guess they say nothing. It's up to you to decide when your observable sequence ends. If you don't call `OnCompleted` in the event of cancellation, then it won't end. Depending on your specific task it might be either good, or bad. Personally, I tend to think that it should end in this case, maybe with a special flag that distinguishes successful and cancelled completion.

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead, there are a number of bugs with the code above, but there's actually a better way to do this altogether (Warning: Coding in TextArea ahead):

```
countObservable = Observable.Timer(new ControlScheduler(this));

var buttonObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(
    x => button1.Click += x, x => button1.Click -= x);

countObservable
    .TakeUntil(buttonObservable)
    .Subscribe(x => /* Do stuff */);
```

Comment: This solution works great for the example above where I have a simple counter (Think i give a bad example), but the problem is when i have a really long running process where Im using databases and services and I need to check before procceding to the next step... I will change the example above...